# Zero divisors in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{2}+x-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ - polynomials with integer coefficients

$I = (x^2+x-1)\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Am i right that classes of factor-ring $R/I$ represented in the next form:
$K_{a,b} = ax+b$?

Also I have question: there is no zero divisors in the ring $R$ and factor-ring $R/I$?

I highly appreciate all answers. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, since $I$ is generated by a MONIC polynomial of degree $2$, every equivalence class of the quotient ring $R/I$ can be represented in the form of a linear polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. This is mainly because $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a domain (in fact, UFD), and since the leading coefficient of $x^{2}+x-1$ is a unit, one can perform polynomial division by $x^{2}+x-1$ to obtain an element of the class with degree strictly less than $2$.

Your second question is somewhat related to your first. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is also a UFD, hence a domain. This is a famous theorem of Gauss's - it is sometimes called Gauss's lemma. You may want to see [these wonderful notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/12.pdf) for more information. Note that $x^{2}+x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (why? You might appeal to any number of classical results here, including the rational root theorem, though there are more elementary methods). Hence, $I$ is a prime ideal, and therefore $R/I$ is also a domain.

Comment: Thank you for your time, notes and this explanation. Now I understood this things properly.

Comment: I have one new question, if you will see this:
Is it true, that $R/I$ is not field, because there is no inverse element for multiplication?

Comment: @Nikita: $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal. If $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ were a PID, then this would be easy - any ideal generated by an irreducible element is maximal in a PID! However, things are unfortunately not so simple in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD but not a PID (for example, the ideal $(2,x)$ is not principal). Can you determine whether $I$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Try tinkering with this, and feel free to comment again if you get stuck.

Comment: (Of course, you could also show that a certain element is not invertible, as you suggested :). It's good to have facility with multiple methods though, I think.)

Comment: I've used idea about inverse element to prove that. Now I'm thinking about isomorphism of $R/I$, tried to build isomorphism with matrices but I had no success on this way. Can you tell me in what way I should work, to describe isomorphism of $R/I$?